# media9 cross section add section caps by default in view file

Tags: 3d, media9, embedding, javascript

I would like to know how to enable the 'add section caps' feature by default in a predefined view of a 3D object in PDF using the media9 package. Right now the part is hollow after making a crossection with a predefined view and I have not been able to find an answer in the documentation of the media9 package.

Here is the shell part together with the option to be enabled by default:
[image]

And here the code in the .vws file:
[image]

Maybe there is an option like "sectioncapsvisible=true" somehow?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance, Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.23 of package `media9` adds two new options, `SECTIONCAPPING=true|false` and `SHOWTRANSPARENT=true|false`, for use in the subsection `CROSSSECT` of a 3D views file. Because these settings do not have a JavaScript representation, they cannot be detected by "Get Current View" of the 3D annotation's context menu and have to be added manually.

Comment: I get the following error when trying to add the options: Package media9 Error: Line 23: Unknown option `SECTIONCAPPING'. I tried adding them to the 'option list of \includemedia' and the view file. I'm using Overleaf. Any advice?

Comment: Overleaf is not up to date, it raises its packages to their current versions only a few times per year. But you could try uploading [media9.sty](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/media9.sty) to you project directory on Overleaf. Also, `SECTIONCAPPING`can be used only in a `CROSSSECT` section of a views file and *not* enabled globally as a command option.